# Android GPS Not Turning Off When Activity Is Changed

Tags: android, gps, mapactivity

I am experiencing a mass amount of battery consumption on one of my Android apps, and I believe it is due to the GPS being turned on, but never being turned off when a new activity starts.  I am working with a code base that I inherited from someone else.  Please let me know if you have a solution to this problem.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Start the tracker in manual dispatch mode...
    GoogleAnalyticsTracker.getInstance().startNewSession(sessionCode, this);

    //Get url to get survey and tags 
    urlSurveyFilter = Global.getInstance().getUrlStringForRequest(R.string.jsonsurveys, this);
    urlJsonTag = Global.getInstance().getUrlStringForRequest(R.string.jsontagrequest,this);


    //to use the KinseyAppActivity.this like a global variable
    _this = this;

    //set the layout from my xml
    setContentView(R.layout.main1);

    Global.getInstance().locatePosition(MapViewActivity.this);

    // button to choice the filter
    Button filterButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.filterButton);
    filterButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sendTrackingEvents("Click Filter Button", "Open the filter", "clicked", 1, "/MapActivity");
            showDialog(0);
        }
    });
```

Comment: did my solution work for you ?

Comment: From what I can tell yes, but could you give me a way simply checking whether the GPS is on or off.  I'd like to print a few things in log cat to guarantee that it is working.  Thanks!

Comment: " if(provider.contains("gps") " condition is what you want, i guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use this method

```
    private void turnGPSOff(){
    String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);

    if(provider.contains("gps")){ //if gps is enabled
        final Intent poke = new Intent();
        poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");
        poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
        poke.setData(Uri.parse("3")); 
        sendBroadcast(poke);
    }
}
```

where you want to stop gps. E.g. this can be onDestroy , onStop etc.